# PowerShell - Export Outlook Calender

Tags: powershell, outlook, exchange-server

I´m using at the moment 2 Exchange Mailboxes in Outlook.
I´m now searching for a way to sync the calendars.
The manual way to export/import the calendar as a PST file is okay for me.

But how can I Export and Import the Calendar with PowerShell on my Client?
(I´m not the Exchange Admin)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: have a look at the outlook.application com object, you should be able to accomplish it using this

Answer (score 4):

If you have access to the exchange shell, and you are member of the 
ImportExport Role (Exchange 2010 and above) you can run this:

```
New-MailboxExportRequest -Mailbox $YourMailbox -IncludeFolders "#Calendar#" -FilePath "\\Share\Calendar.pst"
```

If not:

You can use Outlook ComObject like this:

```
$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$NS = $Outlook.GetNamespace('MAPI')
$Store = $NS.Stores | ? {$_.displayname -eq "mymailbox@mail.com"}
$Calendar = $Store.GetDefaultFolder('olFolderCalendar')
$Outlook.Session.AddStore("c:\temp.pst")
$PST = $ns.Stores | ? {$_.filepath -eq "c:\temp.pst"}
$Calendar.CopyTo($PST)
```

Comment: Ok thanks a lot! This is working for the export very well. But how can I import the calendar? Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

New-MailboxImportRequest -Mailbox $YourMailbox -FilePath "\Share\Calendar.pst" -IncludeFolders "#Calendar#"

Same would be apply to the New-MailboxImportRequest cmdlet.